# How to insert a node into a complete binary tree in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

As we all know, when inserting into a complete binary tree we have to fill all the children for all the leafs from left to right. I have the following method that inserts a node into a complete binary tree.

```
//fields
private T item;
private int size;
private CBTree<T> left, right;

//add method
public void add(T item) 
{
    if(left == null)
    {
        left = new CBTree<T>(item);
        size += left.size;
    }
    else if(right == null)
    {
        right = new CBTree<T>(item);
        size += right.size;
    }
    else if(!((left.left != null) && (left.right != null)) && 
           ((right.left == null) || (right.right == null)))
    {
        left.add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        right.add(item);
    }
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that after the 11th node it adds the 12th node to the left child of 8 instead of 6. I understand that this is happening because the following line is reassigning the root of this tree to be the left child of the root.

```
left.add(item);
```

So it is changing the root to 2. Is there a way to change the root back to its original value? I am trying to accomplish this without using stacks and queues.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890929/how-to-implement-a-complete-binary-tree-using-recursion-without-comparing-the-va

Comment: @JimMischel My question differs from that of which you linked. Their solution looks to fail at the same spot as mine. I have since figured out the correct way of implementing the method, thanks to Dukeling. I will post the solution in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Dukeling's answer, the correct way to implement the method was to mathematically determine if the subtree was full. Here is the code:

```
//fields
private T item;
private int size;
private CBTree<T> left, right;

//add method
public void add(T item) 
{
    if(left == null)
    {
        left = new CBTree<T>(item);
    }
    else if(right == null)
    {
        right = new CBTree<T>(item);
    }
    else if(leftFull())
    {
        right.add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        left.add(item);
    }
    size++;
}

//Checks if the left subtree is full
public boolean leftFull()
{
    int used, leafs = 1;
    while(leafs <= size + 1)
    {
        leafs *= 2;
    }

    leafs /= 2;
    used = (size + 1) % leafs;
    if(used >= (leafs / 2))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the other user helped show the problem, then why did you not accept his answer?

Comment: @T.Woody They actually provided some code, which is arguably more helpful than the original answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's not sufficient to just check children of children to determine which side to go to, because as soon as the tree reaches height 4 that won't work any more, since children of children of the root won't change from that point forward yet we can still go either left or right.

2 approaches come to mind:

1. Have a `complete` variable at each node.

   A node with no children is complete.

   A node with 2 complete children of equal size is complete.

   Whenever update the tree (insert or delete) you update this variable for each affected node as well.
2. Mathematically determine whether a subtree is complete based on the size.

   A tree of size `2^n - 1` is complete (for some `n`).

   Note: this will only work if we're not allowed to freely delete elements without keeping the tree complete.

For either approach, when doing an insertion, we go left (`left.add(item)`) if either of these conditions are true:

- the left subtree is not complete
- the left and right subtrees are of the same size (both complete, meaning we're increasing the height with this insertion)

I'll leave the implementation details to you.

---

Note: you need to also update size when doing `left.add(item);` and `right.add(item);`. You could probably just stick a `size++` in the `add` function, since we're adding 1 element so size increases by 1 no matter what.

Comment: What is worse: An SO user coming back to say "Never mind, I figured it out" w/out accepting an answer, or for the SO user to say that you gave them the right answer, but make their own answer in return?